# I want to Create an array based on a key in another multidymentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array as below:

```
Array
(
[2011000001] => Array
    (
        [UHID] => SRHID1
        [REGDT] => 2011-10-31 00:00:00.000
        [DocId] => 1
        [RefDocId] => 1
        [PROID] => PR000011
    )

[2011000002] => Array
    (
        [UHID] => SRHID2
        [REGDT] => 2011-10-31 00:00:00.000
        [DocId] => 1
        [RefDocId] => 44
        [PROID] => PR000001
    )

[2011000004] => Array
    (
        [UHID] => SRHID4
        [REGDT] => 2011-11-01 00:00:00.000
        [DocId] => 61
        [RefDocId] => 1
        [PROID] => PR000011
    )

[2011000008] => Array
    (
        [UHID] => SRHID21
        [REGDT] => 2011-11-01 00:00:00.000
        [DocId] => 1
        [RefDocId] => 6
        [PROID] => PR000001
    )
)
```

Now I want to create an array like this:

```
 [UHID] => Array
    (
        [0] => SRHID1
        [1] => SRHID2
        [2] => SRHID4
        [3] => SRHID21

    )
```

I created it using `foreach` loop successfully. All I want to know is is there any direct function that extracts all values of a specified key?

Comment: `foreach()` loop, 3 lines of code, at least try something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the nifty function for PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$result['UHID'] = array_column($array, 'UHID');
```

If not:

```
$result['UHID'] = array_map(function($v) { return $v['UHID']; }, $array);
```